# Unexpected Identifier while selecting elements from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm tearing my hair out about a Syntax Error: Unexpected Identifier that I can't figure out. I know what the error means, but as far as I can tell there's nothing wrong.

I've posted the entirety of the script I'm using; what the code is meant to do is allow a user to step through a replay of a gomoku-like game one move at a time. The game data is stored in a csv file that has a row for every move and contains multiple games. Games are identified by an index value.

```
var replayArray = [],
    rawData=[[]];

function importData(matchID,gI) {
    var dataPromise = $.ajax({
        url:"./data/" + matchID + ".csv",
        dataType: 'text'
    })
    dataPromise.then(function(data) {
        rawData = data;
        rawData = String(rawData);
        rawData = rawData.split(/\n/);
        for (h = 0; h < rawData.length; h++){
            rawData[h] = String(rawData[h]).split(",");
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        dataToArray(gI,actionReplayKeydown);
    })
}

function dataToArray(gI,cb) {

    var f = 0;
    var g = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
        var turnArray = [];
        if (parseInt(eval(rawData[i][1])) === gI) {
            turnArray[0] = colorToNumber(eval(rawData[i][5]));
            turnArray[1] = parseInt(eval(rawData[i][6]));
            replayArray[g] = turnArray;
            g++;
        } else {
            doNothing();
        }
    }

    cb(replayArray);
}
```

The dataToArray function is where the problem occurs, in the line

```
if (parseInt(eval(rawData[i][1])) === gI) {
```

I think dev tools has been indicating the problem occurs at rawData[i][1], but rawData is a two dimensional array and the indexing should work fine (the first column of rawData contains the game index, and I want all rows where the value of the game index equals the index of the queried game).

The rest of the code follows but is not afaik problematic.

```
function colorToNumber(inputColor) {
    if (inputColor === "B" ) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

function actionReplay(inputArray) {

    addStone(parseInt(inputArray[f][1]),parseInt(inputArray[f][0]));
    f++;
    $('#whiteLastMove').remove();
    $('#blackLastMove').remove();
    if ((f+1)===inputArray.length){
        $(document).off('keyup').on('keyup',function(e){
            if (e.keyCode === 32) {
                clearBoard();
                createTiles(M,N);
                replayArray = [];
                rawData="";
            }
        });
    }
}

function actionReplayKeydown() {
    $(document).off('keyup').on('keyup',function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            actionReplay(replayArray);
            evaluateWin(0);
            evaluateWin(1);
        } else if (e.keyCode === 32) {
            clearBoard();
            createTiles(M,N);
            replayArray = [];
            rawData="";
        } else {
            doNothing();
        }
    });
}

function playReplay(matchID,gI) {
    openCurtain(doNothing);
    importData(matchID,gI);
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm just not figuring it out on my own.

Comment: Is there any reason that you are trying to execute the value in rawData -  eval(rawData[i][1])

Comment: Yup, the error might come from the `eval` call, it's best not to use it unless you really need to. Can you give us an example of what rawData contains ?

Comment: Try changing:
`if (parseInt(eval(rawData[i][1])) === gI) {`
to
`if (parseInt(rawData[i][1]) === gI) {`

Comment: Or even `if (parseInt(rawData[i][1],10) === gI) {` the second argument will save your life when `parseIt` returns a number in base 8 on some implementations because your value will start with `0`

Comment: Every element of rawData is a string; it looks something like ["0","0","0","B","0","22","000000000000000000001","00000000000001000000", "111.111.111.111"] etc. Getting rid of eval there and a couple other places seems to have fixed it; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is a js syntax error in the value of rawData[i][1]. If you use your debugger you can see the value and check whether it's valid js for eval to execute.

Comment: I've already done this; the expression pareseInt(eval(rawData[i][1])) evaluates just fine in the console for all appropriate values of i (and doesn't work when i is greater than the number of rows in rawData)